# MPU6050 raw sensor data, zero

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, avr, gyroscope, i2c

I am trying to get raw values of `ACCEL_OUT` from `MPU6050 (GY-521 module)`. I can read `WHO_AM_I` register and I can write to `PWR_MGM_1 (0x6B)` register and change it default value from `0x40` to `0x00` ( when I write to register, I can read `0x00`). and interrupts are handled fair, I need to access raw data of sensors. but when I read `ACCEL_OUT` registers, for example (`ACCEL_ZOUT_L`) it just return `0x00`. I spend a whole night and a whole day on this problem and nothing good happened at all.
Any advise would be great help.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was I2C NACK and STOP in read command.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? What did you do to fix the problem?